Ignore/Exclude Views in Entity Framework Core database-first
I'm using EF Core 8.0.4 and I want to use my existing database. But there are about 1000 views in the database. I don't want to use them for my project anymore. How can I avoid EF Core from scaffolding them into my new project?
I'm try searching a lot but can't find solution

Use ef-core power tools.

You can specify the tables to generate at the command line with the --table switch in dotnet ef scaffold.
